# Python csv reader: ignoring special characters

Tags: python, csv, escaping, quotes

I am trying to read a tab-delimited file so that I could process it row by row. Some of the delimited fields in a row may be very long strings, containing text with a HTML p tags and other special characters, e.g:

```
"String1"  "String2"  "<p>This should</p>
<p>be read as one</p>
<p>string.</p>"
"String4"   "String5"   "String6"
```

What I get is:

```
"String1"  "String2"  "<p>This should</p>"
"<p>be read as one</p>"
"<p>string.</p>"
"String4"   "String5"   "String6"
```

i.e. the third string is split.

I am trying to read the tsv file with Python csv reader and tried multiple settings of the dialects, but did not figure it out:

```
with open(fileName, 'rb') as tsvHandle:
    tsvHandle = csv.reader(tsvHandle, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\', skipinitialspace)
```

Could someone advice what to do?

Comment: To remove html characters you can use `beautifulsoup`

Comment: So I figured out solution for my problem: it was sufficient to set the dialect to the following option: delimiter='\t', quoting= csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar = '"'

Comment: cool. share that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with:
tsvHandle = csv.reader(tsvHandle, delimiter='\t', quoting= csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar = '"')